# How to block comments and pings?

Tags: comments, spam

Some scum are trying to post spam comments about viagra/casinos to my site.

I have comments disabled at Settings > Discussion

[image]

Somehow they manage to send comments and pings to my site.

I want to disable both. How?

NOTE: This is my bulk edit form. No pings or comments dropdown.

[image]

Comment: I'd check the web logs to work out what requests are generating the comments (are they posting to the usual comments form? to the rest API? are these all / mostly pingbacks?) and then try and debug how they're getting through. At first glance it looks like you've turned everything off yes.

Comment: unfortunately I do not have access to the logs on this account. I have no comment form. Is there any php file I can rename to prevent them from using?

Comment: that only sets the default for new posts/pages, it doesn't go back and update it for existing ones

Answer (score 2):

If you had posts and pages live before you made that change above you will have to go to those pages and turn off pings and comments as well.
[image]
Go to the Page list and in the backend, select all your pages (checkbox) and then under "Bulk Actions" choose edit.  Under the Comments dropdown set to "do not allow".  Click update.

Do the same for your posts, but make sure to also set pingbacks to "do not allow".

Also in the comment moderation area (in your photo above) add the words that keep showing up (viagra, casino, casinos) as example and that will help.

This will take care of posts and pages, but you may have spam coming from form fields to etc, so check the source (look at the content of the spam coming in and make a reference).

Comment: I did that. There is no coments or pingback dropdowns on the bulk edit form.

Comment: i added a screenshot for reference.

Comment: No such dropdowns on my form. I have updated the question with a screenshot of that form.

Comment: is there any PHP file on wordpress instalation i can rename or whatever to prevent them from using for comments/pings?

Comment: What about your posts edit screen? (not pages)  Check this link if you want a php function. https://gist.github.com/mattclements/10a997775894c7a0eba1

Comment: thanks I will try that and return to tell the results.